# How to configure in-app purchase (IAP) ad campaign in admob?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, admob, ads

This [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/iap) said:

> In-App Purchase (IAP) promotion ads allow users to make purchases
>   directly within your apps. To receive IAP ads, You must first set up
>   an IAP ad campaign in your AdMob account.
>
> You will only receive in-app purchase (IAP) ads if you specifically
>   configure an IAP ad campaign in the AdMob front end.

The problem is I don't see any option for creating new IAP ad campaign in [Admob](https://apps.admob.com) front-end.

I only see two options:

1) New campaign

2) New house ad campaign

Comment: i guess their just trying to get us ready.

Answer (score 0):

In app purchase ads are now in public beta. See [these directions](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6145807) for how to create a campaign in the AdMob front end.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to choose 'New house ad campaign'. But there are some pre-requirement before you can even see the IAP house ad campaign option. 1) your Google play console account is linked to your AdMob account(if they have the same log in,they are already linked) 2) you need to have at least one apk uploaded to Google play console with In-app product created there. 
Anyway if you are interested to see the In-app purchase house ads format you can find it from my Admob Example App through this link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bindu.bpan.admobexample